# C++ double free or corruption (out)

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include "Accounts.h"

using namespace Vibranium;

void Accounts::LoadTable(RowResult &res) {

        std::vector<AccountsStruct> accounts;
        AccountsStruct accountsStruct;
        for (Row row : res.fetchAll()){
            accountsStruct.id = row[0].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.email = row[1].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.warTag = row[2].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.state = row[4].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.name = row[5].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.lastname = row[6].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.country = row[7].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.dob_month = row[8].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.dob_day = row[9].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.dob_year = row[10].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.balance = row[11].get<double>();
            accountsStruct.created_at = row[12].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.updated_at = row[13].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct.account_role = row[15].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.rank = row[16].get<int>();
            accountsStruct.playerRole = row[17].get<int>();
            Data.emplace_back(&accountsStruct);
        }

    std::cout << "SIZE: " << Data.size() << std::endl;

}
```

`Data` is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataStruct>> Data;`.

To add into the vector I call `Data.emplace_back(&accountsStruct);` which leads me to the following output:

```
SIZE: 2
double free or corruption (out)

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I am sure this line `Data.emplace_back(&accountsStruct);` is causing the issue. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: `AccountsStruct accountsStruct;` <- This is a local variable. It's auto-destructed when you leave the scope of `Accounts::LoadTable()`. But, you seem to store the address of that local variable into `Data` which you claimed is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataStruct>>`. So, `Data` holds this address (which became dangling by the way) and tries to delete it again when `Data` is destroyed. OUCH! You should never store addresses of local variables in a `std::unique_ptr`. For this, there exists `std::make_unique()`.

Comment: I understand. @Scheff can you make a complete answer with some code chance example so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to free memory not allocated with `new` (stack memory, to be precise).

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataStruct>> Data;

AccountsStruct accountsStruct;   // <-- a stack variable

Data.emplace_back(&accountsStruct); // <-- an instance of unique_ptr is created using the address of accountsStruct
```

So when `Data` is destroyed, `unique_ptr` calls `delete` on that pointer (not good!!).

I can think of 2 possible solutions:

1. Allocate `accountsStruct` on the heap using `std::make_unique`:

   ```
    for (auto& row : res.fetchAll()) {
        Data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<AccountsStruct>()); // allocate a new instance on the heap
        AccountsStruct& accountsStruct = *Data.back(); // get a reference to that instance
        accountsStruct.id = row[0].get<int>(); // fill it normally ...
        accountsStruct.email = row[1].get<std::string>();
        accountsStruct.warTag = row[2].get<std::string>();
        . . .
   ```
2. Simplify `Data` to store by-value: `std::vector<DataStruct> Data;`

   ```
    for (auto& row : res.fetchAll()) {
        Data.emplace_back(); // allocates a new instance of AccountsStruct in-place
        AccountsStruct& accountsStruct = Data.back(); // get a reference to that instance
        accountsStruct.id = row[0].get<int>(); // fill it normally ...
        accountsStruct.email = row[1].get<std::string>();
        accountsStruct.warTag = row[2].get<std::string>();
        . . .
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Data should contain a `std::unique_ptr<AccountsStruct>`. I'm afraid, unique_ptr can't be created from AccountsStruct.

So, create struct dynamically, fills by data, create unique_ptr from pointer and add it to vector.

Comment: _"I'm afraid, unique_ptr can't be created from AccountsStruct"_ What makes you doubt exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you provide an address of a local variable to the constructor of std::unique_ptr.

I assume that Data is `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AccountsStruct>>` If AccountsStruct has constructor with no arguments, you can try this:

```
#include "Accounts.h"

using namespace Vibranium;

void Accounts::LoadTable(RowResult &res) {

        std::vector<AccountsStruct> accounts;
        
        // create an instance in the vector and get a reference to it
        // auto will be std::unique_ptr<AccountsStruct>&;
        auto &accountsStruct = Data.emplace_back();
        
        // work with that reference
        for (Row row : res.fetchAll()){
            accountsStruct->id = row[0].get<int>();
            accountsStruct->email = row[1].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct->warTag = row[2].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct->state = row[4].get<int>();
            accountsStruct->name = row[5].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct->lastname = row[6].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct->country = row[7].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct->dob_month = row[8].get<int>();
            accountsStruct->dob_day = row[9].get<int>();
            accountsStruct->dob_year = row[10].get<int>();
            accountsStruct->balance = row[11].get<double>();
            accountsStruct->created_at = row[12].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct->updated_at = row[13].get<std::string>();
            accountsStruct->account_role = row[15].get<int>();
            accountsStruct->rank = row[16].get<int>();
            accountsStruct->playerRole = row[17].get<int>();                
        }

    std::cout << "SIZE: " << Data.size() << std::endl;
}
```

If `AccountsStruct` is derived from `DataStruct` you can use:

```
data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<AccountData>());
```